# What is the difference between the Verbose and Normal setting for ExecutionLogLevel in SSRS 2012?

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I cannot find any real documentation on the ExecutionLogLevel setting in SSRS 2012 (which is expected to be the same as it was in SSRS 2008). What changes when you set the setting to "Verbose"? Do you get more data in the same amount of rows? Do you get more rows? Both?

One thing I'd like to know is if by using "Verbose" would it make it so I don't have to consult the (lame) SSRS LogFile directory when things go wrong? (Seriously: Worst. Log. Files. Ever.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ILSpy, I've determined that "ExecutionLogLevel" setting isn't even used by SSRS 2012; it's not a supported setting. There is no code that references that string anywhere. FYI, I can find code that references "EnableExecutionLogging" and "ExecutionLogDaysKept" (complete with the internal constants defining the default values that SSRS uses).

The Technet article that references it is wrong, or they're planning on implementing it (under the radar) in the future.